# CSS not working if i access localhost from Android

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want access my project from my android. I can access localhost server. But when i access the project

> 192.168.43.191/uajy

all CSS file cant load. I using codeigniter. I was call my css like `<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

How to fix it?

Comment: Which URL does it try to load?

Comment: Try `echo base_url(TRUE);`?

Comment: Also make sure base_url() is not returning something like 127.0.0.1

Comment: Make sure you have set you base url in config.php to something like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';` or on live domain something like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i've done that